# How do I get the elements style in CSS?

Tags: css

is there a way to get the style from one element and apply it to another using only CSS?

```
h1 {
    font-family: Courier New;
}

h2 {
    font-family: h1.font-family;
}
```

Comment: Just extend the rule, `h1,h2{font-family:whatever;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can maybe use css variables for this. Not exactly what you wanted but that works

```
:root {
   --h1-font-family: Courier New;
}
h1 {
  font-family: var(--h1-font-family);
}
h2 {
  font-family: var(--h1-font-family);
}
```